# Group array by exploded key string

Tags: php, arrays, input, grouping, explode

I try to get a multidimensional array from a simple array, after exploding keys.
My array is the result of multiple inputs where the name is dynamically made from an md5 hash and the actual name of the input.
I need to use the md5 strings as keys and group the relative values.

```
$old_array = [
   'ec0e2603172c73a8b644bb9456c1ff6e-name' => 'Bruce',
   'ec0e2603172c73a8b644bb9456c1ff6e-surname' => 'Wayne',
   'ec0e2603172c73a8b644bb9456c1ff6e-city' => 'Gotham',

   '84d961568a65073a3bcf0eb216b2a576-name' => 'Clark',
   '84d961568a65073a3bcf0eb216b2a576-surname' => 'Kent',
   '84d961568a65073a3bcf0eb216b2a576-city' => 'Metropolis',
   //etc
];
```

This is what I'd like to get:

```
$new_array = [
    'ec0e2603172c73a8b644bb9456c1ff6e' => [
            'name' => 'Bruce',
            'surname' => 'Wayne',
            'city' => 'Gotham'
     ],
    '84d961568a65073a3bcf0eb216b2a576' => [
            'name' => 'Clark',
            'surname' => 'Kent',
            'city' => 'Metropolis'
     ] 
];
```

Comment: Where's the difficulty in something as basic as `$new_array = [];
foreach($old_array as $key => $value) {
    list($a, $b) = explode('-', $key);
    $new_array[$a][$b] = $value;
}`?

Comment: you can do by foreach loop or use array_map / array_walk function to get desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Working demo](https://3v4l.org/jfnI6)

Just make your array keys exploded by `-` and store in a new array with that array keys partition value.

```
$array = [
   'ec0e2603172c73a8b644bb9456c1ff6e-name' => 'Bruce',
   'ec0e2603172c73a8b644bb9456c1ff6e-surname' => 'Wayne',
   'ec0e2603172c73a8b644bb9456c1ff6e-city' => 'Gotham',

   '84d961568a65073a3bcf0eb216b2a576-name' => 'Clark',
   '84d961568a65073a3bcf0eb216b2a576-surname' => 'Kent',
   '84d961568a65073a3bcf0eb216b2a576-city' => 'Metropolis',
   //etc
];

$out = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    $tmp = explode("-", $key);  
    $out[$tmp[0]][$tmp[1]] = $val;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code

```
print "<pre>";
$reverse = array();
array_walk($old_array, 'walk');
$reverse = walk($reverse);

function walk($val, $key = 0)
{
    static $new_array;
    if (!$new_array)
    {
        $new_array = array();
    }
    $nums = explode('-', $key);
    if ($nums[0])
    {
        $new_array[$nums[0]][$nums[1]] = $val;
    }
    return $new_array;
}
print_r($reverse);
```

Answer (score -1):

This code output the same:

```
<?php

$old_array = [
   'ec0e2603172c73a8b644bb9456c1ff6e-name' => 'Bruce',
   'ec0e2603172c73a8b644bb9456c1ff6e-surname' => 'Wayne',
   'ec0e2603172c73a8b644bb9456c1ff6e-city' => 'Gotham',

   '84d961568a65073a3bcf0eb216b2a576-name' => 'Clark',
   '84d961568a65073a3bcf0eb216b2a576-surname' => 'Kent',
   '84d961568a65073a3bcf0eb216b2a576-city' => 'Metropolis',
   //etc
];

$new_array = [];

foreach($old_array as $key => $value){

    $ky = explode('-',$key);
    $new_array[$ky[0]][] = $ky[1];
    $new_array[$ky[0]][] = $value;

}

print_r($new_array);
```