# Need to split array using key value

Tags: php, arrays

Need to split single array to multiple array using key word.
This is the input array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => "handrail-18"
    [1] => "handrail-17"
    [2] => "handrail-16"
    [3] => "safetyLine-26"
    [4] => "safetyLine-25"
)
```

I have try this below code but still I didn't getting proper solution

```
 $components_nodetype = array();
foreach($components_parenttype as $item) {
    if (isset($item) && $item === "safetyLine") {
        $components_nodetype[] = $item;
    }
}
```

I need output like below. This array based on handrail and safetyLine it should get separate by two array

```
$Array1 = Array
(
    [0] => "handrail-18"
    [1] => "handrail-17"
    [2] => "handrail-16"
)
```

```
$Array2 = Array
(   
    [0] => "safetyLine-26"
    [1] => "safetyLine-25"
)
```

Comment: Related topic for grouping by key prefix: [Group associative array data by key prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51947631/2943403) and [Is there better way to split array by key starts with certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56288292/2943403) and [Group data by leading portion of keys and push values into each group as indexed elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71807994/2943403)

Comment: Also: [Group array by exploded key string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37342800/2943403) and [split an array into multiple part based on key pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45709832/2943403) and [how to break an array into sub arrays based on array key in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28968835/2943403)

Comment: Sakshi bhalchandra I hope you can see the deleted answer. Please check and use any one of them. The accepted one is not a good solution at all. It will fail when more keywords will come into your array.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can solve this by iterating through the array and checking if each element contains the keyword ("handrail" or "safetyLine") by using strpos. If it does, you can add it to the corresponding output array.

```
$handrailArray = array();
$safetyLineArray = array();

foreach ($inputArray as $item) {
    if (strpos($item, "handrail") !== false) {
        $handrailArray[] = $item;
    } elseif (strpos($item, "safetyLine") !== false) {
        $safetyLineArray[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have unique insights to share with this community, please do not post them on this duplicate page.  Instead, post your unique advice on the page nominated as the dupe target at the top of this page.  Stack Overflow's goal is to get all unique insights on a given target in one place.

Comment: This is a poor solution. What happens if more indexes will come? How many if-else will be implemented? You need to provide a more accurate solution that can handle any number of keywords. Resolving an issue anyhow is not a good approach, it should be more accurate and scalable.